# ListNav plugin and sharepoint list not working for me

Tags: list, jquery

Im trying to use this plugin to filter through an employee list  but until i hard code the HTML its doesnt match any entries :(
Im using ajax to write out the data to suit the html and im sure my output is fine. But when i load the page its all showing zeros and no matches :(

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http:///sites/dev/SiteAssets/ListNav/jquery-listnav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http:///sites/dev/SiteAssets/ListNav/demo.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http:///sites/dev/SiteAssets/ListNav/listnav.css"/>


<script type="text/javascript">

// begin work to call across network
var requestUri = "http://dev-melsp01:1655/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Contact')/items?$select=FirstName,Title";
// execute AJAX request
$.ajax({
url: requestUri,
type: "GET",
headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function(data){
//alert(data.d.FullName);
var newRows = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {

                newRows +="<li>";
        newRows +="<a href='#'>" + data.d.results[i].FirstName + "</a>";
        newRows +="</li>";


}


$("#demoSix").prepend(newRows);
//Working and can print out the html fine
alert(newRows);

},
error: function(){
alert("Failed to get customer");
}


});


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document ).ready(function() {
$('#demoSix').listnav({

    });
});

</script>

//appending data to the UL element
<ul id='demoSix' class='demo'></ul>
```

Comment: figured it out.Move the listnav(jquery plugin) below the prepend and it worked.Not sure if this was the best practice though